# Traces are not showing

Tags: python, plotly

plotly version 4.2.1, python 3.7.3

Trying to explore plotly with the below simple example, but the plot is showing without traces.(I note both axis limits do not change with different data ranges)

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go

x = np.arange(10)    #np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = x**2             #np.random.randn(100)


fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace = [go.Scatter(x=x, y=y+5,
               mode='markers',  name = 'marker',)]
fig.add_trace = [go.Scatter(x=x, y=y,
               mode='lines',  name = 'mylines')]

fig.update_layout(title='line charts',)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank your for accepting my answer. By now you have gained more that 15 reputation points and earned the right to up-vote questions and answers. In your quest to learn plotly I humbly suggest you take a look at other posts under the [plotly] tag and award your upvotes where you find useful contributions. Doing so can even earn you the Suffrage and Electorate badges. I'm looking forward to more questions and answers from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fig.add_trace()` is not a variable that you can assign values to. It's a function that among other elements can take `go.Scatter()` as an argument.

**Corrected code:**

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go

x = np.arange(10)    #np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = x**2             #np.random.randn(100)


fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y+5,
               mode='markers',  name = 'marker'))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y,
               mode='lines',  name = 'mylines'))

fig.update_layout(title='line charts',)
fig.show()
```

**Plot:**

[image]